# Liquibase parameter in sql file with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

In my changelog xml file I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">


    <changeSet id="seed_testtest_18" author="me" failOnError="true">
        <sqlFile path="dml/seed-data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    </changeSet>


</databaseChangeLog>
```

In the dml/seed-data.sql file I need to use a variable based on spring boot profile that is being used

```
INSERT INTO ${keyspace}.TESTTEST (ID, NAME, AGE, EMAIL, PHONE) VALUES (14, 'Dennis Vo', 20, 'dennis.n.vo@chase.com', '272-324-8912');
```

in my application.yml file I have keyspace defined as below

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local

  liquibase:
    parameters:
      keyspace: localkeyspace
```

However the value of keyspace is not being used when I run the application. Is there anyway to do this when using a sql file?

Comment: i mean spring-boot "supports" liquibase (intialization on "main" or "test" application start-up), but i think "spring property resolution in changelog files" ...is "music of the future" :-) (do you have reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use a different schema/keyspace (cassandra!?) in different environments!?

Make your sql "schema/keyspace-free":

```sql
INSERT INTO TESTTEST -- ...
```

Then in `application-local.properties`, we would:

```properties
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=localkeyspace
```

...in  `application-int.properties`:

```properties
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=int_keyspace
```

...in  `application[-prod].properties`:

```properties
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=prod_keyspace
```

This will (hopefully) route your(1) scripts to the correct schema per environment.

---

If there is "more dynamics" in the sqls than this (built-in liquibase configuration), we must: maintain multiple sql's of the same changeset (-> contexts: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/existing-project.html), and then can write:

```xml
<changeSet id="seed_testtest_18_local" context="local" author="me" failOnError="true">
  <sqlFile path="dml/seed-data_local.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="seed_testtest_18_uat" context="uat" author="me" failOnError="true">
  <sqlFile path="dml/seed-data_uat.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="seed_testtest_18_prod" context="prod" author="me" failOnError="true">
  <sqlFile path="dml/seed-data_prod.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
```

and in `application[-profile].properties|yaml`:

```properties
spring.liquibase.contexts=local # ...or e.g.: !local, uat & prod, ${spring.profiles.active}..., matching changelog contexts!
```

[`LiquibaseProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseProperties.java)

---

Another (build-time) approach: maven profiles + resource filtering/antrun/...